# UITableView with columns

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to display a list items in a tableview but with about 5 different columns similar to a spreadsheet.  The last column would be a UIButton (which I know is possible).

Is it possible to achieve this type of design with the UITableView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an easier way of doing this by following one of Apple's samples:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableViewCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {

/*
 Create an instance of UITableViewCell and add tagged subviews for the name, local time, and quarter image of the time zone.
 */

UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

/*
 Create labels for the text fields; set the highlight color so that when the cell is selected it changes appropriately.
*/
UILabel *label;
CGRect rect;

// Create a label for the time zone name.
rect = CGRectMake(LEFT_COLUMN_OFFSET, (ROW_HEIGHT - LABEL_HEIGHT) / 2.0, LEFT_COLUMN_WIDTH, LABEL_HEIGHT);
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
label.tag = NAME_TAG;
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:MAIN_FONT_SIZE];
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[label release];

// Create a label for the time.
rect = CGRectMake(MIDDLE_COLUMN_OFFSET, (ROW_HEIGHT - LABEL_HEIGHT) / 2.0, MIDDLE_COLUMN_WIDTH, LABEL_HEIGHT);
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
label.tag = TIME_TAG;
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:MAIN_FONT_SIZE];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[label release];

// Create an image view for the quarter image.
rect = CGRectMake(RIGHT_COLUMN_OFFSET, (ROW_HEIGHT - IMAGE_SIDE) / 2.0, IMAGE_SIDE, IMAGE_SIDE);

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
imageView.tag = IMAGE_TAG;
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];    

return cell;
}
```

Comment: I know it is an old question but can you link the apple example for me?

Comment: @Juzzz: I know this answer is late but in case someone else finds this question: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318

Comment: @alokoko thank you for linking, I did not noticed the comment.

Answer (score -1):

A customized workaround, you can make your own table cells this way:

```
   @interface MyOwnCell : UITableViewCell {
    NSMutableArray *columns;
 }

- (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position;
@end



@implementation MyOwnCell

- (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position {
[columns addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:position]];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.25);

    for (int i = 0; i < [columns count]; i++) {
        CGFloat f = [((NSNumber*) [columns objectAtIndex:i]) floatValue];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, f, 0);
    }


    [super drawRect:rect];
}

@end
```

Refer to TheLearner's solution which is actually more easier :)